# Mapping Dataset row getting "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface"

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8, functional-programming, parquet

Trying to map to Dataset row but having a lot of issues, I get eclipse error "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface" on `map(r -> new MapFunction<r, List<Tuple3<Long, Integer, Double>>>()`. The code is below:

```
Dataset<Object> df1 = session.read().parquet(tableName).as(Encoders.bean(Object.class));

        JavaRDD<List<Tuple3<Long, Integer, Double>>> tempData = df1.map(r -> new MapFunction<r, List<Tuple3<Long, Integer, Double>>>(){


            // to get each sample individually
            List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> samples = zipWithIndex((r.getString(9).trim().split(",")));

            // Gets the unique identifier for that pos.
            Long snp = r.getString(1);

            // Calculates the distance for this pos for each sample.
            // i.e. 0|0 => 0, 0|1 => 1, 1|0 => 1, 1|1 => 2
            return samples.stream().map(t -> {
                String alleles = t._1();
                Integer patient = t._2();

                List<String> values = Arrays.asList(alleles.split("\\|"));

                Double firstAllele = Double.parseDouble(values.get(0));
                Double secondAllele = Double.parseDouble(values.get(1));

                // Returns the initial SNP id, patient id and the distance in form of Tuple.
                return new Tuple3<>(snp, patient, firstAllele + secondAllele);
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because of lack of clarity, I am just giving my UNTESTED suggestions.

Assuming that you are referring to 
`org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction`.

I see some series of problems,

1. Usage of `r` as type in the generic in the line  `MapFunction<r ..>`
2. The definition of the anonymous function is not correct, either use the lambda expression saying,

```

```
JavaRDD<List<Tuple3<Long, Integer, Double>>> tempData = df1.map(r -> () {
// your definition
}
```

```

Or, move your code to the method of the class,
```

```
JavaRDD<List<Tuple3<Long, Integer, Double>>> tempData = df1.map(r -> new MapFunction<theRespectiveType, List<Tuple3<Long, Integer, Double>>>(){
public List<Tuple3<Long, Integer, Double>> call(theRespectiveType variable)
{
// your implementation here
});
```

```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am just wondering what the `theRespectiveType` is going to be in the second option, is it `Object` in `Dataset<Object>`?

Comment: It's the type of whatever you mentioned as r

Comment: I am trying to map each row in the Dataset with `df1.map(r ->`, so I can process each row and create RDD out of them. So r is supposed to be row or is that approach wrong?